# Building a match site

Tags: php, html

The if statement I have in the code below is giving me the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project4\matches-submit.php on line 31

I have tried every single possibility and I can't find the error.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$numberofSingles;$i++)
{
    $information = explode(",",$matches[$i]); //explode every single at time
    if ($gender==$information[1]) { //check for gender,if same bye bye
        unset($matches[$i]); //check for gender
    }
    else if ($information[4]!=$os) { //checks for os type
        unset ($matches[$i]);
```

Comment: There's something funny about an `undefined offset` on a dating site :)

Comment: Check if `$information[1]` is set before trying to use it. Use `isset()` for this purpose.

Comment: many missing brackets in ur code

Comment: "I have tried every single possibility"

Comment: @M.chaudhry: DO NOT modify the OP's original code with your 'corrections'. If you have a suggested fix, then post it as an answer.

Comment: okay got it Thank You @ the Blue Dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check if $information has entries:

```
if(!empty($information)&&isset($information[1])&&$gender==$information[1]){....
```

You have to check if there's information in the array at offset 1, if not you'll get the error you're looking at